# How to Make Server Side Authentication Secure with vb .net windows app?

Tags: vb.net, security, authentication, secure-coding

m trying to make an VB .NET Windows Form app that authenticate to my website by POST request!
if user login info is valid it says "welcome" and application authentication is successful!
my website is coded with php + mysql!

**problem is it is insecure and can be bypassed by many techniques..**

> HOW TO MAKE SECURE APP IN VB .NET that auth server side? 
>   any method? please provide codes if possible!any code or
>   any other best language to make it most secure?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an authentication function in PHP Web Service Class File . 
And from your windows application, you can call the authentication function in that PHP web service  .

Here is the sample link on how to create a web service in PHP : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/671437/Creating-Web-Service-Using-PHP-Within-Minutes